# Icons misaligned with the new design

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The design update messed up all my icons:

[image]

Tested on Chrome and Safari on MacOS. Also tried clearing the browser caches to no avail.

Comment: I'm not sure it's associated with this update - it appears to be happening everywhere - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270001/site-icons-misaligned

Comment: Looks fine on my Safari on OS X.

Comment: No repro on Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: Time to call the X-Files then `;)`

Comment: We're investigating.

Comment: @bluefeet, it seems that Martin's comment on the other thread is on the spot. My laptop is Retina Display, just tested on Chrome/Win7 in another machine and it seems fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We accidentally icons in wrong size for a while there.

Should be fixed now, sorry!

Comment: Yep, all good. Cheers!